# JSF, website first setup and external configuration files

Tags: java, jsf-2, jdbc, tomcat7

I have a website written in JSF backed by MySQL database running on Tomcat 7. Now there is only one missing part - project first setup/installation. I want my war when deployed for the first time to offer you installation/first time setup with following steps:

1. Setup database - enter mysql parameters needed to successfully connect to mySQL server.
2. Write those parameters into some external file for further use (of course encrypted).
3. Install database - take a file with SQL inside that creates all the tables in database.
4. Create first user etc.
5. Delete installation files.

Similar steps are used in PHP Content Management systems like Drupal. I know perfectly how to work with files in Java. I also know, that I can't change content inside a jar once it's deployed and running, so I have to put my files with SQL and database parameters somewhere else.

**My questions are**

1. Where can I put these configuration files to make them readable ? And how ?
2. Is there another way to achieve this goal ? What is commonly used by Java developers ?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPA(Java persistent API) and put all this configuration on persistance.xml and set the schema generation to create Table also the things related to role and user is dependent to application server.
JPA use ORM(object relational mapping) to map between you objects (entity) and database tables